# Removing Size and font-size from child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to remove some element attributes from the divs. My divs are generated automatically. I want to iterate through each div and child divs and want to remove all `font-size (font-size: Xpx)` and `size` which inside `font tag <font size="X">`.

These are the examples of my div.

```
<div id="headline" class="headline" style="position: word-break: break-all; background-color: rgb(90, 88, 84); width:300px;height:250px">
  <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(1, 69, 18);">
    <div>
      <div>
        <font color="#ffffff" size="6" >
          <b>This is&nbsp;</b>
        </font>
        <b style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: xx-large;">a Test&nbsp;</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <b style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: xx-large;">Demo&nbsp;</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <b style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: xx-large;">csa</b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div id="headline" class="headline" style="position: absolute; width: 186px; height: 50px; ">
  <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(249, 249, 251);">
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 204, 153);">
      <font size="4">Expansion Pack</font>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am reading the divs like.

```
$('#headline').find('*').each(function() {
    // font-size remove
    //size inside tag remove
});
```

But how can i remove the font-size and size if they are in the child element, sometimes only font-size are present and there is no `<font>` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to be more explicit with your selectors. Something like this should work:

```
// Select all elements with a style attribute that contains font-size, and
// remove the inline font-size property
$('[style*="font-size"]').css('font-size', '');

// Select all font elements with a size attribute, and
// remove the size attribute
$('font[size]').removeAttr('size');
```

You may want to make the selectors more specific to avoid modifying content unexpectedly. For example:

```
$('#headline [style*="font-size"]').css('font-size', '');
```

**NOTE:** This solution uses [jQuery attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

**EDIT:** See the comments from Charlie about performance. Attribute selectors are much slower than most other selectors, but I'd bet that in most use cases the speed differences won't matter.

Comment: Seems legit. +1 on using a proper selector. OP should learn more about selectors like the attribute selector etc, and using wild cards, maybe elaborate on the construction of the selector if you get a chance. Maybe talk about the performance hit that such a complex selector takes as well.

Comment: @Charlie - Thanks! I added a link to the docs. Are you aware of noticeable performance problems with jQuery's attribute selectors, or was that just a general statement about complex selectors?

Comment: @BryanDowning - Yes, Attribute selectors are far less performant than using # for id, or . for class... and those are even less performant than just using vanilla javascript for querying the DOM. http://jsperf.com/asdfasdfasdfasdf9873847yh9dj89384d (Look at the OPS/SEC not the percentage) If you get your self into a situation where you can't use a class, or an id, you should rethink the implementation, because there's probably a better way. No way to tell by the context he has given us though. If performance is not desired, then use jquery, and use attribute selectors because it's sugar.

Comment: @Charlie - I'm seeing about 91,000 opts/second in Chrome for the slowest result. I guess I feel like that's fast enough :)

Answer (score -1):

try to loop those elements which got 'font-size':

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).css('font-size', '');  // set the value as empty string
)};

$('b').each(function(){
    $(this).css('font-size', ''); 
)};
```

see [jQuery Documentation on CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: Too broad. Why would you loop over every div? Clearly, it should have at least some form of scope.